# Do the events of the Rise of Skywalker retcon any of the books, comics etc

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker, retcon

Given all the events of *The Rise of Skywalker*, but mainly

> the fact that Palpatine is alive and pulling all the strings

Does this retcon any of the new books, comics or TV series written post *The Force Awakens*? I am thinking about anything involving Snoke or the First Order mainly. Or are they written in such a way that they still make sense knowing that

> Palpatine was really behind it all?

Note I am only talking about books, comics etc. set in the Force Awakens Star Wars universe and not anything from the Legends books.

Comment: For a non-Palpatine related retcon, they completely change Poe's backstory.

Comment: How so? guessing he was never a spice runner?

Comment: According to the comics, he was born to two Rebels and was in the New Republic/Resistance his whole life.

Comment: They also retconned Luke's X-wing to be flyable, instead of missing a wing (see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/180138/21154).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The largest retcon is within *The Last Jedi*. We saw Luke's X-Wing in dismal shape

[image: Luke's X-Wing]

One of the wings is apparently broken and some of the hull has disintegrated, which is about what you would expect for anything kept under ocean water. [One canon book even notes Luke made a door from that wing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/180138/62709). Considering that

> Luke pulls it out in perfect working order and Rey flies it to Exegol

they will probably retouch the scene when they release the box set on DVD/Bluray/Disney+ (which [seems to be standard operating procedure at this point](https://www.washingtonpost.com/arts-entertainment/2019/11/13/han-shot-greedo-disney-plus-maclunkey/))

Comment: Maybe Han force healed it as he raised it up :p

Comment: -1 for the "they will probably retouch the scene when they release the box set on DVD/Bluray/Disney+" part. The movie didn't have anything resembling your picture to begin with, so there's nothing to retouch. [Here's is the screenshot from the original (2018) Blu-ray release.](https://i.imgur.com/oduJnUh.jpg)